# Calculating votes - PHP and MySQL voting system

Tags: php, mysql

how can I create a script to calculate the voting results for each option knowing that sometimes a question can have up to 4 options?

Comment: needs a bit more explanation

Comment: sum, join and group by. The basics of sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your tables are respectively named `table1`, `table2` and `table3`, one can do:

```sql
SELECT   Question_ID, Option_ID, SUM(Vote)
FROM     table1 LEFT JOIN table2 USING (Option_ID)
GROUP BY Question_ID, Option_ID
```